# cant hide an <a> tag when the screen resolution is below 600px

Tags: javascript, css, html

What i want to achieve is when i change the resolution of my browser to below 600px the  tags except home will disappear. and only appear again when the sandwich button is clicked but the (admin control) and (sign out) is not disappearing. I think is because of i make the "display" attribute of both to "block" using javascript. that cause a conflict with the css code (.topnav a:not(:first){ display:none;}. i spend hours in fixing it and searching for a solution but with no luck. so any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated.

this is what it look like

[image]
[image]

here is the php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="speaker.php">Speakers</a>
    <a href="about.php">About</a>
    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    <a href="reservation.php">Reservation</a>
    <a href="signOut.php" id="signOut" style="float:right">Sign Out</a>
    <a href="myAccount.php" id="user" style="float:right; text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></a>
    <a href="signUp.php" id="signUp" style="float:right">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="signIn.php" id="signIn" style="float:right">Sign In</a>
    <a href="adminControl.php" id="adminControl" style="float:right; width:110px;">Admin control</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img id="img1" src="img/homepage-image1.jpg">
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img id="img2" src="img/homepage-image2.jpg">
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img id="img3" src="img/homepage-image3.jpg">
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div id="dots">
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
</div>
<div id="index-welcome"><p>Welcome</p></div>

<div id="footer" >Copyright 2017</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
</script>

<script>
function ifAdmin() 
{ 
       document.getElementById("signIn").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("signUp").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifNotAdmin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("signIn").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signUp").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifNotLogin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("user").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
function myFunction() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") 
    {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else 
    {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['signedIn']) && $_SESSION['signedIn'] == true) 
        //if login
        {
            if($_SESSION['type'] == 1)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifAdmin();</script>";  
            }
            elseif($_SESSION['type'] == 0)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifNotAdmin();</script>";
            }
        }
        //if not login
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifNotLogin();</script>";   
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{

    /*navbar*/
    .topnav 
    {
        height:auto;
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #4682B4;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        z-index: 10;

    }

    .topnav a:not(:first-child) 
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .topnav a.icon 
    {
        float: right;
        display: block;
        height:15px;
    }
    .topnav a 
    {
        height:15px;
        width:auto;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 16px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .topnav a:hover 
    {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color: black;
        height:12px;

    }

    /*footer*/

    #footer
    {
        background-color: #4682B4;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight:bold;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{       

    .topnav.responsive 
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .icon 
    {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .topnav.responsive a 
    {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

please help i think im near it. i add display:none!important; in the css instead of "display:none" only, like chris Spil said but this happen. the "speaker tag" goes to the top besides "home tag".

[image]

this is what i change.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{

    /*navbar*/
    .topnav 
    {
        height:auto;
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #4682B4;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        z-index: 10;

    }

    .topnav a#speaker
    {
        display:none;
    }

    .topnav a#about
    {
        display:none;
    }

    .topnav a#contact
    {
        display:none;
    }

    .topnav a#reservation
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .topnav a#user
    {
        display:none!important;
    }

    .topnav a#adminControl
    {
        display:none!important;
    }
    .topnav a#signOut
    {
        display:none!important;
    }


    .topnav a.icon 
    {
        display:block;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        height:15px;
    }
    .topnav a 
    {
        height:15px;
        width:auto;
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 16px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .topnav a:hover 
    {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color: black;
        height:12px;

    }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{       

    .topnav.responsive 
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .icon 
    {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .topnav.responsive a#speaker 
    {
        float: none;
        display:block!important;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a#about
    {
        float: none;
        display:block!important;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a#contact 
    {
        float: none;
        display:block!important;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a#reservation
    {
        float: none;
        display:block!important;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a#user
    {
        float: none;
        display:block!important;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a#adminControl
    {
        float: none;
        display:block!important;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a#signOut
    {
        float: none;
        display:block!important;
        text-align: left;
    }


}
```

Comment: Why are you not using bootstrap here. It has this functionality already built?

Comment: because im not familiar with it. and the last time i use it, it mess up my design. maybe im not fully informed of its use and functionality.

Comment: Where's the rest of your css ?

Comment: Might be a [CSS specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) issue.

Comment: Well here is a navigation sample just like you want it if you want to try it out again https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/jVaQyX. Bootstrap is really a very good framework to use in your website. It will make it responsive and if setup good then no additional need of most responsive manual js solutions.

Comment: Here are some useful resource for implementing it with pure css https://codepen.io/FilipVitas/pen/KVXvLP https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/grOZxx Take your pick

Comment: thanks for the suggestion oluwaseye. if i cant find a solution i will try bootstrap. and for the rest of css, i dont add it because its too long and i seperate the css per webpage. so i think the rest of the css is not necessary.

Comment: If your JavaScript sets an inline style using the `style` attribute, you may have trouble overwriting it with an external style sheet. You might consider having your JavaScript toggle a class, instead. See [Selector Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types).

Answer (score 1):

can you try `display:none!important;` on your css code and let me know? Do you have this somewhere live?

Comment: okay thanks i will try it. somewhere live? like online? no i dont.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onclick` to set `visibility` and `opacity` in javascript.

To show you, I created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epykwu9a/2/) as an example.

EDIT: Updated the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML, you don't set the viewport in your `<head>` tag. Did you include this meta tag: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

This tag will give your browser instructions on how to control the dimensions and scaling of your page. More can be read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).